# IndexOutOfBoundsException when reading from a ZipInputStream Java

Tags: java, exception, zip, nullpointerexception, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to implement this algorithm description from a previous question I had here in stackoverflow:

[suppressing or not allowing the access time to be modified java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904265/suppressing-or-not-allowing-the-access-time-to-be-modified-java)

so I implemented as

```
byte[] digest = new byte[this.BUFFER];
        MessageDigest md5;

        try {
            md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

            while(entry.getNextEntry() != null){

                ZipEntry current = entry.getNextEntry();

                if(current.isDirectory()){
                    digest = this.encodeUTF8(current.getName());
                    md5.update(digest);
                }
                else{
                        entry.read(digest, 0, this.BUFFER);
                        md5.update(digest);
                }
            }
            digest = md5.digest();
            entry.close();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

However, I'm getting a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException in the else statement. Does someone know why? Also, could you please tell me if my algorithm was correctly implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `getNextEntry()` twice, instead of once:

```
while (entry.getNextEntry() != null) { // goes to the next entry
    ZipEntry current = entry.getNextEntry(); // goes to the next entry
```

Use this instead:

```
ZipEntry current;
while ((current = entry.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    // use current   
}
```

or

```
for (ZipEntry current = entry.getNextEntry(); current != null; current = entry.getNextEntry()) {
    // use current
}
```

Comment: what should I use instead to know if there is an Entry to be read?

Comment: Size:0
Name:gs_info/
Size:624
Name:gs_info/adobeillustrator.des
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

so when it comes down to read that file and to its task on the MD5, I get that

Comment: else
  {
    read the entry bytes using ZipInputStream.read()
    sha1.update( bytes );
  }

I'm not understanding that part ...

Comment: Are you telling me that you don't understand the code you wrote, and that is not part of the question you asked? What could I do? How is it related to this question?

Comment: You have helped a lot already, thanks! My question is, if it is a file, then I need to read it as a ZipInputStream into a byte[] buffer and then update its md5. I'm not understanding how can I create a ZipInputStream from a ZipEntry

Comment: You don't need to. Once you have called `getNextEntry()` on the stream, you read from it until it returns -1, and then you go to the next entry, etc. Google for "Java IO tutorial" to know how to read from a byte stream.